# Testing if $f_n(x) = \sqrt[n]{x}$ converges uniformly.

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

Given:
$$f_n(x) = \sqrt[n]{x} \; , x \in [0,1]$$

Is the above series of functions converge uniformly? and how do we check it?

Comment: No.  You could start by graphing the first few functions to get an idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more way of seeing it:

Take $x \in (0,1]$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{\frac{1}{n}}=1.$ Now take $x=0$. $\lim_{n \to \infty}x^{\frac{1}{n}}=0 \ne 1$. Hence the function does not converge uniformly, but it converges uniformly for $x \in (0,1]$

Comment: How is $\lim_{n \to +\infty} x^{\frac{1}{n}} = 0$ ?

Comment: Pls see the edit

Comment: Thanks.
So the reason is that each $f_n{x}$ is continuous but $f(x)$ is not ?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at this video lecture: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mB4Yny0T3HA

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: It doesn't converge uniformly in $(0,1]$ (consider for each $n$ the point $x_n=(\frac12)^n$), but it does converge to a continuous function, if that's what you meant.

Comment: If it converged uniformly on $(0,1]$, it would converge uniformly on $[0,1]$, as the functions are continuous. But it is true that it converges uniformly on $[a,1]$ for $a>0$.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

$$\sqrt[n] a\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;,\;\;\forall\,\,0<a\in\Bbb R$$

$$\sqrt[n] 0=0$$

Comment: Ah.
So it is because each $f_n(x)$ is continuous but $f(x)$ is not?

Comment: Well, yes: that's basically the bottom line in the answers and comments...